# Is there any alternative to add an app in SharePoint team site without adding to App Catalog site?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, web-parts, sharepoint-apps

I have SharePoint Team Site Administrator-level permission. I don't have AppCatalog site permission and I don't have SharePoint Administrator-level permission.

I need to add the PnP Modern Script Editor app to the SharePoint Team Site. My user is in the Owner group of that site.

Is there any alternative to adding an app to my site without adding the AppCatalog site collection?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use site level app catalog:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/site-collection-app-catalog

More precisely, you can ask your tenant admin to create one for you, and then you will be able to manage apps in your app catalog yourself. In particular, add that app to your own app catalog.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As I explained in question I have SharePoint Team Site Collection Administrator-level permission. I don't have AppCatalog site permission and I don't have SharePoint Administrator-level permission. So, I will need some alternatives for the same.

Comment: Yes, you can just ask your tenant admin. You are not allowed to install app if it is blocked by tenant admin, there are no workarounds. It's called security :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is currently no alternative. If we want to add an app to SharePoint site, we need to [use the site collection app catalog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/site-collection-app-catalog).

Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Do you have any further questions about this thread? If you have any questions or progress, you can contact me in time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As I explained in question I have SharePoint Team Site Collection Administrator-level permission. I don't have AppCatalog site permission and I don't have SharePoint Administrator-level permission. So, I cannot create a Site-level App Catalog. So, I will need some alternatives for the same.